# promise and blocking function that returns a value

Tags: typescript, promise

I am trying to return a value from a function that calls a third lib which uses promises.

let's say i have a function (typescript):

```
static get(): string {
   return ??? lib.test().done(()=> {return "done"; }).fail(()=>{ return "fail"});
}
```

Inside I am calling a 3rd party library that returns a promise.
How can I return from this function only the value that the lib returns as a promise without rewriting my function? I know this defeats the purpose of promises but the lib does only provide promises as return values.

Comment: No, promises defeat you. It's impossible to block and wait for the async value.

Comment: what about function callback's? lib.test(()=>{})? the lib provides both!

Comment: Yes, you can call a callback from your function (or pass it to the lib). But you cannot return the value from your function (only a promise for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promise represents an asynchronous result that will be available some time in the future.  You cannot make an asynchronous result into a synchronous result in Javascript.  It just cannot be done.  Your operation will need to be treated as asynchronous by the caller and the interface to your method will need to be asynchronous (probably using the promise or you could hide the promise and go back to a plain callback if you wanted).

Comment: this is known, since i am fresh in promises but have a lot of experience in c# TPL i thought there where a construct or method that i could use to make the async call into a sync one without the need to rewrite the function, it's caller and so on.

Comment: @Mantzas - my answer is telling you that in Javascript, there is no way to make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.  It cannot be done.

Comment: thanks. have to drop the lib before refactoring the whole project!